# uniform convergence of an alternating series

Tags: sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

I have this series of functions $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\log(1+\frac{x}n)$ with $x\geq0$.
It's easy to see the pointwise convergence of the series and I also prove that it converges uniform on compact set. The problem is when $x$ is going to infinity: I conjecture that the convergence is not uniform in the whole interval $[0,\infty)$ but I have some problem to prove it.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: If a series of functions converges uniformly on $S$, then all but finitely many of the functions must be bounded on $S$.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know this proposition. Now everything is clear.

Comment: In fact if $\sum f_n$ converges uniformly on $E,$ then $\sup_E |f_n| \to 0.$